# How to make my scroll to top button appear after scrolling

Tags: javascript, html, css

My scroll to top button works perfectly fine, but i want the button to appear only after scrolling down about 20px. I thought my javascript code was the problem but after searching online, I found the same code but it still isn't working. Instead, after scrolling 20px, the button only appears if i refresh. I still don't know what the problem is, but I think it's because I am using a PHP Model View Controller (MVC) framework because i created a test Html file and tried the same code there and it worked. The code is below:

```js
var scrollTop = document.getElementById("scrollTop");

window.onscroll = function(){
    scrollfunction()
};
function scrollfunction(){

    if( document.body.scrollTop > 20 || document.documentElement.scrollTop > 20){
        scrollTop.style.display = "block";
    } else {
        scrollTop.style.display = "none";
    }
}

scrollTop.addEventListener("click", function(){
    window.scrollTo({
        left: 0,
        top: 0,
        behavior: "smooth"
    })
})
```

```css
/*Scroll to top button*/
#scrollTop{
    font-size: 380%;
    right: 30px;
    bottom: 30px;
    width: 5%;
    height: 10%;
    text-align: center;
    position: fixed;
    border: 1px solid rgb(0, 0, 255);
    background-color: rgb(183, 183, 255);
    color: rgb(0, 0, 255);
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: 0.5s;
    text-decoration: none;
}
#scrollTop:hover{
    background-color: rgb(123, 123, 255);
    transition: 0.5s;
}
#scrollTop:active{
    background-color: rgb(0, 0, 148);
}
```

```html
 <p>Some default text</p>
 <p>Some default text</p>
 <p>Some default text</p>
 <p>Some default text</p>
 <p>Some default text</p>
 <p>Some default text</p>
 <p>Some default text</p>
 <p>Some default text</p>
 <p>Some default text</p>
 <p>Some default text</p>
 <p>Some default text</p>
 <p>Some default text</p>
 <p>Some default text</p>
 <p>Some default text</p>
 <p>Some default text</p>
 <p>Some default text</p>
 <p>Some default text</p>
 <p>Some default text</p>
 <p>Some default text</p>

<button id="scrollTop">
           <i class="fas fa-arrow-up"></i>
</button>
```

Comment: i suggest you to use https://nicescroll.areaaperta.com/

Comment: @hoseininjast - Why would you suggest a jQuery plugin when there's nothing in the question mentioning jQuery? I mean, installing a bloated library together with an extra plugin just to get one button to show seems a bit excessive.

Comment: FYI - I removed the `PHP`-tag since the question doesn't have anything to do with that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add default `display:none` to your scrolltop button, so its hidden by default

Rest of your code looks fine

```js
var scrollTop = document.getElementById("scrollTop");

window.onscroll = function(){
    scrollfunction()
};
function scrollfunction(){

    if( document.body.scrollTop > 20 || document.documentElement.scrollTop > 20){
        scrollTop.style.display = "block";
    } else {
        scrollTop.style.display = "none";
    }
}

scrollTop.addEventListener("click", function(){
    window.scrollTo({
        left: 0,
        top: 0,
        behavior: "smooth"
    })
})
```

```css
.content{
height:2000px;
}

/*Scroll to top button*/
#scrollTop{
    display:none;
    font-size: 380%;
    right: 30px;
    bottom: 30px;
    width: 5%;
    height: 10%;
    text-align: center;
    position: fixed;
    border: 1px solid rgb(0, 0, 255);
    background-color: rgb(183, 183, 255);
    color: rgb(0, 0, 255);
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: 0.5s;
    text-decoration: none;
}
#scrollTop:hover{
    background-color: rgb(123, 123, 255);
    transition: 0.5s;
}
#scrollTop:active{
    background-color: rgb(0, 0, 148);
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="content">
  </div>
</body>

<button id="scrollTop">
           <i class=""></i>
</button>
```

Comment: I just forget to make the default display "none" and that was just the solution. Thanks a lot